# Help me rewrite this command?

Tags: vertical-alignment, moderncv

so I'm completely new to TeX, and just started using a resume template that I found on github. Within that template, there's a class file with an environment "cventries" and a command "cventry":

```
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{12.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \multicolumn{2}{L{17cm}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}} \\
  \end{tabular*}
}
```

Now, this essentially renders on screen like this

```
 Title                                Location                           
 Position                             Date 
 Description
```

but I want it to render like this whenever I don't fill in the position or date fields:

```
 Title                                Date
 Description
```

So, in a nutshell, I'm wondering whether I need to make another command or use some combo of \ifempty in order to make this happen. Thanks in advance for any help.

Oh, and if you need any additional context to answer my question, [here's the full class file](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/blob/master/awesome-cv.cls)

Comment: This looks like it is out of moderncv. What do you want to use it for?

Comment: You want to show the "Date" when you don't fill in the Date field?? Perhaps you meant "position or location fields"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By only providing a code fragment, it makes it tough, because we have to imagine what all the undefined commands might mean.

First I assumed a typo in the question that you wanted the alternate format if position or **LOCATION** were absent (since why would you want the date if date were absent).

Then I assumed that the `\Xstyle` commands were merely text styles...that's a pretty safe assumption.

I also assumed a reasonable definition of `\ifempty`, but it may not be what your class assumes.

Finally, I had to modify the format of the table, since `L` and `R` columns were not defined.  In those cases, I replaced those column types by `p`.  When actually implementing your fix, you should change those back the way they were.

The code already had a test if title **AND** location were absent, so I nested two additional tests, if the position were empty, and if not, if the location were empty.  I did it this way since the question specified an **OR** condition on the missing fields, not an **AND** condition.

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\def\entrypositionstyle#1{\textit{#1}}
\def\entrytitlestyle#1{\textbf{#1}}
\def\entrylocationstyle#1{\textit{\textbf{#1}}}
\def\entrydatestyle#1{\textsc{#1}}
\def\descriptionstyle#1{\textup{#1}}
\def\ifempty#1#2#3{\ifx\relax#1\relax#2\else#3\fi}

\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
%  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{12.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} p{12.5cm} p{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}% WHEN TITLE & LOCATION EMPTY
      {%
        \ifempty{#1}{\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}% WHEN POSITION EMPTY
        {%
          \ifempty{#3}{\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}% WHEN LOC EMPTY
          {%
            \entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
            \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\%
          }
        }
      }
%    \multicolumn{2}{L{17cm}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{p{17cm}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}} \\
  \end{tabular*}
}
\begin{document}
\cventry{position}{title}{location}{date}{description}
\par\hrulefill\par
\cventry{position}{}{}{date}{description}
\par\hrulefill\par
\cventry{}{title}{location}{date}{description}
\par\hrulefill\par
\cventry{position}{title}{}{date}{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]